# Unable to get cordovaCapture to work using ngCordova on ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am unable to get cordovaCapture.captureVideo to work. Using cordovaCamera lets me use the camera to take photos and choose photos from the library without any problems but I am trying to to use cordovaCapture to use take a video on iOS, I would also like to get a thumbnail or image preview of the video to show on the view once the video is taken.

I have included the code below which uses both cordovaCamera and cordovaCapture. I have followed the examples on ngCordova website.

```
.controller("CameraController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaCapture) {
  $scope.takePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
      quality: 75,
      cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function (err) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
  }

  $scope.choosePhoto = function () {
    var options = {
      quality: 75,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function (err) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
  }

  $scope.captureVideo = function() {
    var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };

    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
      // Video data
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: What about Android, did you try to take a video `ng-click="captureVideo()"` on Android?

Comment: @TomislavStankovic have tried on Android as well, does not seem to work. However, Camera does work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you in the meantime managed to solve the problem? If you need further assistance I'm here.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you use `$cordovaCamera` and `$cordovaCapture` inside controller.

This means that you need to install both

`$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera` from [$cordovaCamera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)

and

`$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture` from [$cordovaCapture](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/)

---

If `takePhoto()` works, but `captureVideo()` does not, this means that you did not install [$cordovaCapture](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/).

Comment: It is installed already. I got the message "Plugin "cordova-plugin-media-capture" already installed on ios" when i tried the command

Comment: Try to put inside controller only code from `$cordovaCapture` and see will it work (captureAudio, captureImage, captureVideo). Maybe you will have to remove and reinstall the plugin.